# Python filter dataframe by iterating through list of words in one column and returning rows where any word from list can be found in another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, lambda, zip, iterable

I am working with one large dataframe which contains multiple columns

Cutdown version of the data is as follows (the ROW column has only been inserted to demonstrate  issues I've experienced, explained further below)

**df1**

| ROW | search_words | text_to_search |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | currency,CrossCurrencySwap,COPTIONS | text1 text2, "text3": TEXT4; Currency |
| 2 | Exotic Bond | text1, text 2 / text 3 'Exotic Bond' |
| 3 | JPN,Japan | Japan, Asia, JPN, EMEA, US |
| 4 | BasisSwap,basis swap,swap | EMEA |
| 5 | EMEA | US, Japan |
| 6 | irs,interestrateswap,interest rate swap | [NULL] |
| 7 | forward | FRAforwardrateagreementforwardbondtrade |
| 8 | equity swap, equityswap | equity, warrant, convertible, swap |

The goal is to filter dataframe so only those rows where words in the search_words column that exist in text_to_search column are contained within it

Once filtered, the dataframe should look like this:

**df1**

| search_words | text_to_search |
| --- | --- |
| **currency**,CrossCurrencySwap,COPTIONS | text1 text2, "text3": TEXT4; **Currency** |
| **Exotic Bond** | text1, text 2 / text 3 '**Exotic Bond**' |
| JPN,**Japan** | **Japan**, Asia, JPN, EMEA, US |
| **forward** | FRA**forward**rateagreementforwardbondtrade |

As shown, the search_words column may contain one or more word on which to search.  Where search_words contains a phrase (as in ROW 8 "equity swap") the WHOLE phrase must exist in text_to_search in order to find a match.

The text_to_search column has no discernible format so I cannot split the text into a list of words to use to compare against each word from the search_words column.

I started using the following line of code:

df1 = df1[df1.apply(lambda x: x.search_words in x['text_to_search'], axis=1)]

This returns no correct results.

I then tried reformatting the search_words column so that instead of a ',' delimiter, the words are separated by a pipe '|' so that the data looks like this: currency|CrossCurrencySwap|COPTIONS (and so on...)

And using the following code to try to establish a match:

df1 = df1.loc[df1['text_to_search'].str.contains('|'.join(map(str, df1['search_words']))))]

This line of code doesn't work either.  It appears to join *all* words in the search_words column together and match *all* search_words to each line of text in the text_to_search column.  In this way, I am getting false matches.   For example ROW 5 is returned as a match because 'Japan' is found in the joined search_words string even though 'Japan' is not found in the search_words column in ROW 5.

What I think I need is something like this:

df1 = df1[df1.apply(lambda x: words_in_string(zip(x.search_words, x.text_to_search)), axis=1)]

def words_in_string(search_words, text_to_search):
word_count = 0

for word in search_words:
word_count = word_count + text_to_search.lower().find(word.lower())

return (word_count > 0)

I'm certainly not going to win any prizes for this code.  It's awful.  And it doesn't work.  Please could you point me to where I am going wrong and how to resolve this?

THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way :

```
ser1 = df["search_words"].str.split("\s*,\s*")
ser2 = df["text_to_search"].str.lower()
​
m = [any(w.lower() in t for w in lst) for lst, t in zip(ser1, ser2)]
​
out = df.loc[m]
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)
                          search_words                           text_to_search
0  currency,CrossCurrencySwap,COPTIONS    text1 text2, "text3": TEXT4; Currency
1                          Exotic Bond     text1, text 2 / text 3 'Exotic Bond'
2                            JPN,Japan               Japan, Asia, JPN, EMEA, US
6                              forward  FRAforwardrateagreementforwardbondtrade
```

Comment: Beautiful answer, I could only hope to write such a solution in 4 lines.  This is the second time you've provided a useful answer to my problem, and I thoroughly appreciate it.  Thank you so very much.  I am embarrassed to say I have been struggling through this for days, you seem to have come up with this in minutes!  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to do it using `apply()`:

**Way #1**: Use `re.search()` with a regex pattern created from `search_words` with `Series.str.replace()` to replace comma delimiters (potenitally with whitespace to the right and left) with the regex special character `|`:

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'search_pat':df.search_words.str.replace('\s*,\s*', '|', regex=True),
    'text_to_search':df.text_to_search})
import re
mask = df2.apply(lambda row: 
    bool(re.search(row.search_pat, row.text_to_search, flags=re.IGNORECASE)), 
    axis=1).tolist()
res = df[mask]
```

**Way #2**: Create the mask using `Series.str.contains()` instead of `re.search()`:

```py
mask = df2.apply(lambda row: 
    pd.Series(row.text_to_search).str.contains(row.search_pat, case=False).squeeze(),
    axis=1).tolist()
```

**Output**:

```
                          search_words                           text_to_search
0  currency,CrossCurrencySwap,COPTIONS    text1 text2, "text3": TEXT4; Currency
1                          Exotic Bond     text1, text 2 / text 3 'Exotic Bond'
2                            JPN,Japan               Japan, Asia, JPN, EMEA, US
6                              forward  FRAforwardrateagreementforwardbondtrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you seek?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "search_words": ['word1, word2, word3', 'word4, word5, word6', 'word7, word8, word9'],
        "sentence" : ['this will not match', 'this will match word4', 'this will match word8 word9']
     }
)

df['matched'] = df.apply(lambda row: [search_word for search_word in row['search_words'].split(', ') if search_word in row['sentence']], axis=1)
df[df["matched"].str.len() > 0]
```

Original DF looks like:

```
          search_words                     sentence
0  word1, word2, word3          this will not match
1  word4, word5, word6        this will match word4
2  word7, word8, word9  this will match word8 word9
```

Final df looks like:

```
          search_words                     sentence         matched
1  word4, word5, word6        this will match word4         [word4]
2  word7, word8, word9  this will match word8 word9  [word8, word9]
```

EDIT: the list comprehension in the lambda function might seem complicated, so here is the equivalent in function format:

```
def my_function(row: pd.Series):
    search_words = row['search_words'].split(', ')
    result = []
    for search_word in search_words:
        if search_word in row['sentence']:
            result.append(search_word)
    return result
```